# Remove line pattern script in Python not fully functional

Tags: python, parsing, design-patterns, logging

For logs parsing, I need to remove a pattern in a log file:

Pattern:

**Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1 "**

Log sample:

```
# This line has to be kept
2014-03-03 09:50:20,2014-03-03 09:50:20,560,Success Audit event,Accès aux objets,Security,LA\USER1,LA-SERVER1,"Objet ouvert : Serveur de l’objet : Security Type d’objet : File Objet : \vol\vol01\PROD\prod.conf Identificateur du handle : 554 Identificateur de l’opération : - ID du processus : 2050 Nom du fichier image : Server Soft Utilisateur principal : user1 Domaine principal : LA ID d’ouv. de session principale : (0x0, 0x9596) Utilisateur client : 1.2.3.4 Domaine client : - ID d’ouv. de session client : - Acces : Lecture données (ou liste de répertoire) Écriture données (ou ajout fichier) Ajout données (ou ajout sous-répertoire ou créer instance de canal) WRITE_DAC Privilèges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d’accès : 0x40007 "
# This line has to be removed
2014-03-03 09:52:20,2014-03-03 09:50:20,560,Success Audit event,Accès aux objets,Security,LA\USER2,LA-SERVER1,"Objet ouvert : Serveur de l’objet : Security Type d’objet : File Objet : \vol\vol01\PROD\prod.conf Identificateur du handle : 554 Identificateur de l’opération : - ID du processus : 2050 Nom du fichier image : Server Soft Utilisateur principal : user1 Domaine principal : LA ID d’ouv. de session principale : (0x0, 0x9597) Utilisateur client : 1.2.3.5 Domaine client : - ID d’ouv. de session client : - **Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1 "**
# This line has to be removed
2014-03-03 09:53:20,2014-03-03 09:50:20,560,Success Audit event,Accès aux objets,Security,LA\USER3,LA-SERVER1,"Objet ouvert : Serveur de l’objet : Security Type d’objet : File Objet : \vol\vol01\PROD\prod.conf Identificateur du handle : 554 Identificateur de l’opération : - ID du processus : 2050 Nom du fichier image : Server Soft Utilisateur principal : user1 Domaine principal : LA ID d’ouv. de session principale : (0x0, 0x9597) Utilisateur client : 1.2.3.6 Domaine client : - ID d’ouv. de session client : - **Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1 "**
```

I found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714491/remove-line-pattern) (thx to ATOzTOA) to do the job (I just added sys module):

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1] 
def delete_line(dello):

    data = open(fname).readlines()

    i = 0
    for line in data:
        if dello in line:
           data.pop(i)
        i += 1

   open(fname, "w").write("".join(data))
delete_line("Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1\"")
```

When I run the script, it didn't remove the 2 lines of logs which contain the pattern : only one of the two.

I have to run once or twice again the script to delete all the lines

I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't increment `i` when calling `pop()`. Also, you shouldn't use `pop()` when iterating over a list. This is because if you remove an element from the middle of a list, then you skip some items while iterating.

You should rewrite `delete_line()` as follows:

```
def delete_line(dello):
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = [line for line in f if dello not in line]
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(data))
```

(Note that there is room for improvement.)

An another problem is that you are giving `delete_line()` the wrong argument: there's a space between `0x1` and `"`. This is the correct line:

```
delete_line('Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1 "')
```

By the way, there's already an excellent program that filters out lines from a file: it's [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) (with the `-v` option).

Comment: @lexa: sorry, I didn't notice some other problems.

Comment: Adding else to the original code didn't work, but your second code rewriting works perfectly. Indeed, logs has many lines (I have one with 50 000 lines), I 'm gone to try it out !

Comment: @lexa: the `else` didn't work because you are looping through the list while you are modifying it. A way to work around this problem would be to use `for line in list(data)`, but that's overkill.

Comment: I agree grep is good but i have to do a cross platform tool...anyway thanks for your attention and help

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your error locally. However, I will suggest that you can try the python replace method instead.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm
str.replace(old, new[, max])

which will search for the  replaced it with what you want  in your string.

Therefore, the one possible solution to your problem will be :

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1] 

def delete_line(dello):
    cleaned_data = []
    data = open(fname).readlines()

    for line in data:
        line = line.replace(dello, "") 
        cleaned_data.append(line)

    open(fname, "w").write("".join(data))    


delete_line("Acces : Lecture donnees (ou liste de repertoire) Privileges : - Nombre de SID restreint : 0 Masque d acces : 0x1\"")
```

You may replace your for loop with a list comprehension

```
    clean_data = [line.replace(dello,"") for line in data]
```

Comment: I have "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line' referenced before assignment" . Have you the same ?

Comment: no problem, anyway I tested your code and the pattern is not removed..have you tried by your side ?